# Multijob related query in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have a multijob in Jenkins. This multijob contains following jobs:
i) Job 1: that sync and build from GIT in an Unix box workspace
ii) Job 2: it runs the API test execution from the same workspace

I want to run the Job 1 and 2 both only if there is code change checked in into GIT. Currently I have selected "Build only if SCM changes" option for both of the jobs. But the issue I am facing is, if there is code change then the Job 1 is running but the Job 2 is not running if there is no test case related changes in the Unix box workspace directory.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a use case for a build pipeline where you do a build first and than execute test. Check https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md and/or https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/

Comment: Do I need to change the existing multijob configuration? Please suggest thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below mentioned plugin

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger

Refer to the section: Usage with the Git Plugin in the above link

[image: Git Config]

Configure both your jobs as per the image above and both your jobs should be triggered if there is a change checked in to git repo.

Comment: Actually the Job 2 should be dependent on Job 1. What I have found that if the "Build only if SCM changes" is checked against Job 1 then if there is no check in into GIT then the Job 1 doesnot run(it doesnot create any build number). I want a specific logic for this if the Job 1 doesnot run then Job 2 in the same multijob wont run and vise versa.

Comment: The requirement is not clear, can you explain in detail. As i understand if a change is detected in git then both jobs should be triggered. if there is no changes job 1 or job 2 wont be triggered.