# Multijob related query when multiple job is running in a single multijob

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a multijob in Jenkins. This multijob contains the following jobs:

**i) Job 1:** syncs and builds from git in a Unix box workspace

**ii) Job 2:** runs the API test execution from the same workspace

I want Job 2 to be dependent on Job 1. But if the "Build only if SCM changes" is checked against Job 1, then, if there is no checkin into git, then Job 1 does not run (it does not create any build number). If Job 1 does not run, then I want Job 2 in the same multijob not to run either.

If there is a code change in git, then JOB 1 will run and then Job 2 should run also. Is there any specific code I need to write, or is there is any configuration change required in multijob.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multijob related query in Jenkins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588328/multijob-related-query-in-jenkins)

Answer (score 0):

So What you try to do is just to trigger Job2 from Job1?

There is no need for any code for that,
simply trigger job2 from job1 :

[image]

Comment: Thanks Shachar. You meant to put the 2nd job as downstream of 1st one..correct! But the 2nd job is also available inside multijob along with 1st job. I have found this 2nd job is run irrespective of 1st job run or not. Is there any solution for this.

Comment: Well, I might not understand what you are asking but if you check  "Build only if SCM changes"  against Job 1 then it will run only when git is pushed, same for job 2 just check the box  "Build only if SCM changes" for job 2, no?

Comment: That's correct...I had done it too. The issue I have faced again is if there is minor code change then Job 1 run. As I said Job 1 syncs from GIT repository. Job 2 runs the test execution from local directory(where it syncs the code base from GIT through Job 1). The Job 2 doesnot run if there is no change in  test suite folder. I want to run this Job 2 once the Job 1 is run if Job 1 has not been run then Job 2 will not run. Please note these jobs are put in a Multijob. Please help.